# how can i select data on time range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time, range

i have data frames belows, and i wanna select time range.

for example i have below data, and i wanna select 06:00~08:00
every day .  Date, Time is multi indexed index

```
Date        Time     a      b    c
2018-01-09  5:15:00 20.55   0   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:30:00 20.57   0   -3.07
2018-01-09  5:45:00 20.33   0   -3.44
2018-01-09  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
2018-01-09  8:15:00 23.25   15438   -3.48
2018-01-09  8:30:00 23.44   16218   -3.65
2018-01-09  8:45:00 23.65   14666   -3.14
2018-01-09  9:00:00 24.01   14686   -3.1
.....
```

so result should be belows

```
Date        Time     a      b    c
2018-01-09  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
2018-01-09  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-09  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-09  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-09  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-09  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-09  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-09  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-09  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
2018-01-10  6:00:00 20.31   0   -2.95
2018-01-10  6:15:00 20.76   26738   -2.88
2018-01-10  6:30:00 21.4    22462   -2.77
2018-01-10  6:45:00 21.84   20033   -3
2018-01-10  7:00:00 22.17   20010   -3.28
2018-01-10  7:15:00 22.38   18133   -2.82
2018-01-10  7:30:00 22.75   18254   -3.14
2018-01-10  7:45:00 22.93   17039   -3.22
2018-01-10  8:00:00 23.13   15934   -3.27
```

how can i select data on time range(06:00~08:00) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with comparing [timedelatas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
a = pd.Timedelta(6, unit='h')
b = pd.Timedelta(8, unit='h')
df = df[pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).between(a,b)]
```

Another solution is create `DatetimeIndex` and select by [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])
df = df.between_time ('6:00', '8:00').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
          Date     Time      a      b     c
3   2018-01-09  6:00:00  20.31      0 -2.95
4   2018-01-09  6:15:00  20.76  26738 -2.88
5   2018-01-09  6:30:00  21.40  22462 -2.77
6   2018-01-09  6:45:00  21.84  20033 -3.00
7   2018-01-09  7:00:00  22.17  20010 -3.28
8   2018-01-09  7:15:00  22.38  18133 -2.82
9   2018-01-09  7:30:00  22.75  18254 -3.14
10  2018-01-09  7:45:00  22.93  17039 -3.22
11  2018-01-09  8:00:00  23.13  15934 -3.27
```